# How to make layer appear with no transition

Tags: framerjs

I'm making a mock up of Snapchat. When you hit the camera button on the Camera Page layer, this should bring you to the Edit Photos Page (another layer). How do I make the Edit Photos Page layer just appear like Snapchat does without `.showNext` or `.overlayTop`?

**Code**

```
# Create FlowComponent, show layerA 
flow = new FlowComponent
flow.showNext(step1)

snapchat.cameraButton.on Events.Click, ->   
   flow.showNext(step2)
```

**Interaction**

[image]
[image: Edit Photo Page]

Answer (score 1):

Set `animate` to `false` in `showNext` to transition instantly.

With your code:

```
snapchat.cameraButton.on Events.Click, ->   
   flow.showNext(step2, animate: false)
```